# How to convert xml tag using xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to convert an xml using xsl file, the question is: I have several tag with the same name but different attribute, I've to convert them changing their name with the name of their attribute and print their value.
Here the sample:

```
<INDEX_FIELDS>
  <FIELD NAME= "Field1" VALUE= "value1"/>
  <FIELD NAME= "Field2" VALUE= "value2"/>
  <FIELD NAME= "Field3" VALUE= "value3"/>
  <FIELD NAME= "Field4" VALUE= "value4"/>
</INDEX_FIELDS>
```

I want make it like this sample:

```
<INDEX_FIELD>
  <FIELD1>VALUE1</FIELD1>
  <FIELD2>VALUE2</FIELD2>
  <FIELD3>VALUE3</FIELD3>
  <FIELD4>VALUE4</FIELD4>
</INDEX_FIELD>
```

I could use only xsl transformation. Someone can give me any help? I've visited W3C school site, tried several method but nothing seem's to work. Thanks to anyone will answer.

Here my xslt:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:sap="http://www.sap.com/sapxsl" version="1.0">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
  <ROOT>
   <HEAD>
    <TAG><xsl_value-of select="ROOT/HEAD/TAG"/></TAG>
     <-- Several tag -->
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
    <DOCUMENTS><--Here it is a list of documents -->
    <xsl:for-each select="ROOT/BODY/DOCUMENTS/DOCUMENT">
    <DOCUMENT>
     <xsl:for-each select="INDEX_FIELDS/FIELD">
    enter code here
     </xsl:for-each>
    <-- Closing tags -->
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to show something you have tried? You might not actually be that for off the solution, you see. Thank you!

Comment: Also, can you say whether you can use XSLT 2.0 (or 3.0), as converting strings to upper case is much easier in XSLT 2.0 is much easier than in XSLT 1.0. Thank you!

Comment: Can you add your XSL template to the question? It sounds like you're trying to process everything inside one xsl:template statement, there are other approaches that might work better.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I've added some information =)

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="FIELD">
        <xsl:element name="{@NAME}">
            <xsl:value-of select="@VALUE"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
Try it.
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answere. This code seem's good but I've to put it on a larger context: I've an header, body and several tags, in my xslt doc I've a big xsl:template with all tag inside like:

<xsl:template>
<header><tags><xsl:value-of></tags></header>
<body><tag1/><tag2/><index_field><xsl:for-each><????></xsl:for-each></index_field></body>.

If I put the template into the loop it gave me error

Comment: please give me your full input

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use for-each loops. 
You can also use  `xsl:template match` rules that match one part of your XML document. This rule will be executed every time a match occurs in the XML

Alternative way to structure your XSLT:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:sap="http://www.sap.com/sapxsl" version="1.0">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
  <ROOT>
   <HEAD>
    <TAG><xsl_value-of select="ROOT/HEAD/TAG"/></TAG>
     <-- Several tag -->
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
    <DOCUMENTS>
        <xsl:apply-templates match="DOCUMENT"/>--this tells the XSLT processor to find all DOCUMENT nodes and process them. 
    <-- Closing tags --> 
....
<xsl:template match="DOCUMENT">
    <DOCUMENT>
        process your Document nodes here
        <xsl:apply-templates/> --this makes sure the subnodes in the DOCUMENT node are processed. 
    </DOCUMENT>
</xsl:template>
....
<xsl:template match="FIELD">
    <xsl:element name="{@NAME}">
        <xsl:value-of select="@VALUE"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

[XSLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT) tutorial:
http://edutechwiki.unige.ch/en/XSLT_Tutorial_-_Basics#A_first_glance_at_XSLT

XSLT works a bit differently to many programming languages: instead of a list of instructions with subroutines etc, you specify a list of possible nodes in your source document and what to do with them.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'll try it as soon as I can =)