# XSLT: for-each div with part of childs

Tags: html, xml, xslt, foreach, transformation

I'm doing XSL since a short time and I have to create multiple div with a part of the child tag. So I have something like this:

```
<Nodes>
    <Node>
        <Tag>a</Tag>
        <Tag>b</Tag>
    </Node>
    <Node>
        <Tag>c</Tag>
    </Node>
</Nodes>
```

I thought I could do something like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/Nodes">
    <div id="node_{position()}">
        <xsl:for-each select="Node">
            <xsl:value-of select="Tag" />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </div>
</xsl:for-each>
```

And what I need is:

```
<div>
    a
    b
</div>
<div>
    c
</div>
```

But I always get two div with a b c. Instead the first with a b and the other with c.
Do I have to enumerate the tags or something like that?

EDIT:

```
<ProjectTopology>
    <Nodes>
        <Node>
            <Tag>Section1</Tag>
            <Nodes>
                <Node>
                    <Tag>Another section1</Tag>
                    <Tag>Another section2</Tag>
                </Node>
            </Nodes>
            <Tag>Section2</Tag>
            <Nodes>
                <Node>
                    <Tag>Another section3</Tag>
                    <Tag>Another section4</Tag>
                </Node>
            </Nodes>
        </Node>
    </Nodes>
</ProjectTopology>
```

Okay and I'm now looking for something like this:

```
<div id="section_1">
    Another section1
    Another section2
</div>
<div id="section_2">
    Another section3
    Another section4
</div>
```

Comment: See this question, you may not need to use for-each: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52851159/how-to-convert-xml-tag-using-xsl/52854290#52854290

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But I always get two div with a b c.

No, that is **not** the result of applying the code you have posted here. The actual result is:

```
<div id="node_1">ac</div>
```

in XSLT 1.0, and:

```
<div id="node_1">a bc</div>
```

in XSLT 2.0.

There is only one `div` in the output, because there is only one `Nodes` node in the source XML - and the only template that creates a `div` is the one matching `Nodes`.

To get the result you are looking for, you should try something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:template match="/Nodes">
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="Node">
            <div id="node_{position()}">
                <xsl:for-each select="Tag">
                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                </xsl:for-each>
            </div>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
</xsl:template>
```

**Result**

```
<root>
   <div id="node_1">ab</div>
   <div id="node_2">c</div>
</root>
```

or **XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:template match="/Nodes">
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="Node">
            <div id="node_{position()}">
                <xsl:value-of select="Tag" />
            </div>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
</xsl:template>
```

**Result**

```
<root>
   <div id="node_1">a b</div>
   <div id="node_2">c</div>
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks for that fast answer. But I'll get three div now. Every Tag-value in a single div :). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @RobinAegerter First thing: tell us which processor you're using, so that we know if this is XSLT 1.0 or 2.0. Next, edit your question and show a [mcve] using a full stylesheet, not just a snippet.

Comment: I meant your XSLT processor, not your CPU. That could be Saxon or Xalan or libxslt or MSXML or something else in that category. IOW, the application that runs the XSL transform.

Comment: Ah sorry. That's libxslt 1.0

Comment: libxslt is XSLT 1.0. I still don't see a full stylesheet. Have a look at http://xsltransform.net/pNvs5x9 to see the result I get.

Comment: Okay thank you. Now it worked. I forgot to write the `</Node>` after each Tag and open a new. Sorry. But anyway thanks.